# Implement DRY principle with IAsyncDisposable

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

This is a tiny class that creates backup copies of a file so these can be diff'ed to spot the changes compared to last run; used when generating code and so far has proved to be very helpful.

Basically, I reuse the async disposable logic because it doesn't really make sense to write it twice; [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync) simply doesn't bother about that so it's more or less an improvisation.

Example:

```
await using (var history = await FileHistory.CreateAsync("test.cs"))
{
    if (history != null)
    {
        var path = history.Info.FullName;
        var text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, text);
    }
}
```

The first time it is run:

- user writes `test.cs`
- nothing else happens as there's no history yet

The second time it is run:

- user writes `test.cs`
- writes previous version of `test.cs` to `test-backup.cs`

The third time it is run:

- user writes `test.cs`
- writes previous version of `test-backup.cs` to `test-backup-2022-12-31T22-29-28-8881210Z.cs`
- writes previous version of `test.cs` to `test-backup.cs`

And so on, it creates backup copies of the file which can then be compared for changes.

Code:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace abcd;

public sealed class FileHistory : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private FileHistory(FileInfo info, byte[] data)
    {
        Info = info;
        Data = data;
    }

    [PublicAPI]
    public FileInfo Info { get; }

    private byte[] Data { get; }

    private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore(false).ConfigureAwait(false);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~FileHistory()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore(bool disposing)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // NOP
        }

        if (Data.Length is not 0)
        {
            Info.Refresh();

            if (Info.Exists)
            {
                var name = Info.FullName;

                var data = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(name);

                if (data.AsSpan().SequenceEqual(Data) is false)
                {
                    var type = Path.GetExtension(name);

                    name = name[..^type.Length];

                    var path = $"{name}-backup{type}";

                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        var time = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(path);
                        var dest = $"{name}-backup-{time.ToString("O").Replace(':', '-').Replace('.', '-')}{type}";
                        File.Move(path, dest);
                    }

                    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, Data);
                }
            }
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        DisposeAsyncCore(disposing).AsTask().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task<FileHistory?> CreateAsync(string path, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var info = new FileInfo(path);

        byte[] data;

        if (info.Exists)
        {
            await using var stream = info.OpenRead();

            data = new byte[stream.Length];

            // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable

            var read = await stream.ReadAsync(data, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            data = Array.Empty<byte>();
        }

        return cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ? null : new FileHistory(info, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read your code three times and quite frankly it does not make too much sense for me.
(*Maybe I'm just tired, but still it doesn't ...*)

- You have implemented the disposable pattern where your are not freeing up any resources

  - The `FileHistory` does not even own any resources at all
- It seems like the whole implementation is aiming for small file

  - which can nicely fit into a pre-allocated byte array
  - but it would miserably fail with large files
- you are reading the entire file again and compare its content byte-wise

  - why checking the [last modification date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetimeutc?view=net-7.0#System_IO_FileSystemInfo_LastWriteTimeUtc) is not enough?
- `ToString("O").Replace(':', '-').Replace('.', '-')`

  - This date formatting logic is ... well sub-optimal
- Sometimes you try to follow good async practices like: `.ConfigureAwait(false)`

  - Where other times you don't: `.AsTask().Wait()`

---

Apologize if my post felt as offensive that was not my intent.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> As for the date formatting, I don't know, maybe you can suggest better.

Your chosen date time format (`2022-12-31T22-29-28-8881210Z`) is not supported out of the box by any formatter. Mostly because the hyphens are usually used only on the date part, but not on the time component.

So, using `o` or `s` formatter changes only the date part:

```
o: 2023-01-03T08:23:27.1870000Z
s: 2023-01-03T08:23:27
```

There is a class called [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-7.0) which has a [`DateSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator?view=net-7.0) and a [`TimeSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator?view=net-7.0). You can set both to hyphens.

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = culture.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.DateSeparator = "-";
dtfi.TimeSeparator = "-";
```

The problem with this approach is that the `o` or `s` formatter does not take advantage of the `TimeSeparator` :(

```
G: 1-3-2023 8-28-52 AM
O: 2023-01-03T08:28:52.8980000Z
s: 2023-01-03T08:28:52
T: 8-28-52 AM
u: 2023-01-03 08:28:52Z
U: Tuesday, January 3, 2023 8-28-52 AM
```

You can set the `FullDateTimePattern` on the `DateTimeFormatInfo` to specify how the `U` formatter should work

```
dtfi.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss-ffffffZ";
//2023-01-03T08-34-30-538000Z
```

But this is basically the same as providing the above pattern to the `ToString`, which is my recommendation:

```
ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss-ffffffZ")
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

> Finally, AsTask().Wait() is the simplest way I found to apply DRY, I don't like it very much, hence why I asked for a code review :)

There are multiple ways to solve to address this:

- At very least [prefer `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` over `.Wait()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426937/what-is-the-difference-between-wait-vs-getawaiter-getresult)
- It is [not mandatory to implement both interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync#implement-both-dispose-and-async-dispose-patterns)

  - But if you do then you can perform casting to call the proper `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync` method on a given resource
  - Since `FileHistory` does not own any resources this suggestion is not applicable for your code
- Since you have stated that this design is meant for small files that's why using only the synchronous file operations might be fine

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(name);
...
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Data);
...
return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
```

- And last but not least you can do some branching inside the `DisposeAsyncCore`.

  - It feels like a bit dirty but it does its job correctly

```
var data = isSync
    ? File.ReadAllBytes(name)
    : await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(name);
...
if (isSync) File.WriteAllBytes(path, Data);
else await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, Data);
```

Comment: You're right, it doesn't own anything, it's solely for `using` pattern usage. Yes, it is not meant for large files else it would be unpractical. Good one, I haven't thought about checking last modification date instead! As for the date formatting, I don't know, maybe you can suggest better. Finally, `AsTask().Wait()` is the simplest way I found to apply DRY, I don't like it very much, hence why I asked for a code review :)

Comment: @aybe I've updated my post to address the date formatting concern. I'll update the post again to address the `Wait` call.

Comment: @aybe Updated my post again to reply your DRY concern.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your suggestions which I'm going to use :)